# Laravel 5.1 - Migration Error

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, vagrant, virtualbox

I was trying to create a new table, but when I was adding `Schema::create()` part, I copy/pasted it from users so both my original users table, and my new table migrated as `Schema::create('users')` and it ran into a problem as there was 2 tables with same name. When I realised the problem, I fixed it but as I cannot drop the tables now with `php artisan migrate:reset` and `php artisan migrate:refresh` because there are two tables with the same name already now. (Thus, I cannot rollback either).

My DB name is Homestead as original.

The errors I am getting:

> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
>     SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1051 Unknown table 'homestead.users' (SQL: drop table `users`)
>
> [PDOException]
>     SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1051 Unknown table 'homestead.users'

And I am not sure if I mess everything up if I manually log into `vagrant ssh` and drop & create tables manually with:

`mysql> drop database Homestead;`

`mysql> create database Homestead;`

Comment: You can just do `drop database homestead;` and `create database homestead;` then run `php artisan migrate` again.

Comment: jamesking56's answer sorted it out. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following @Jamesking56's comment, I used:

```
mysql> drop database homestead;

mysql> create database homestead;

php artisan migrate
```

and this solves my problem.

Answer (score 1):

In your `down()` function of your migration put this code.

```
Schema::dropIfExists('users');
```

Then execute the following commands from the command line.

```
php artisan migrate:rollback

php artisan migrate
```

**IMPORTANT:** This will drop the users table if the users table exists. if the table does not exists nothing will happen and no error will be giving as MySQL will convert the error to a warning.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all the tables from your database inclusive the migrations table. After removing the tables you can migrate your database as before.