# Migration error: Class 'CreateTasksTable' not found

Tags: php, laravel, migration

I have the class but I get an error, why?

[image: first img]

As you can see it:

[image: you can see it]

Answer (score 0):

Because you didn't run `composer dumpauto` command after you ran `migrate` command.

> If you receive a "class not found" error when running migrations, try running the composer dump-autoload command and re-issuing the migrate command.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/migrations#running-migrations

Comment: You could delete DB manually, create it and run `migrate` command again.

Comment: $ php artisan migrate:refresh                                                                                                                 
  [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]                                                                           
  SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1051 Unknown table 'homestead.tasks' (SQL: drop table `tasks`)

Comment: yes is success but is have a new problem when I use php artisan migrate:refresh | rollback

Comment: I had solved my problem, you can see it:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32417358/laravel-5-1-migration-error

Comment: Well, that is exactly what I've suggested in my previous comment.